# Issue with class clearfix in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I am using twitter bootstrap, i have an issue with `clearfix` class in bootstrap. My html is :

```
<div class="pull-left">This is a text</div>
<hr class="clearfix" />
```

What i am expecting is horizontal line should come in next line of displayed text but it renders at right side of the text. And if when i use `style='clear: both;'` in `hr` than it works fine. Why `clearfix` not doing the same as `clear: both` does ?

Answer (score 40):

The class `clearfix` should be applied to the parent container element

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">This is a text</div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0g0RDA?p=preview)

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-left">This is a text</div>
    <div class="clearfix" />
</div>
<hr />
```

In this case empty clear div is placed next to right of your pull-left div and does clearing.
The matter is if you use `float: left` on the element then it becomes float and the next element after it is placed to the right if there is a free space for it. So you should place all the elements you need to be float with `float: left` (say `pull-left`) in a row and close this sequence with `float: none; clear: both` (say `clearfix`) to stop floating.

Comment: I tried it with <br> tag , not working .. after <div class="clearfix" /> worked !